# Semaphore read lock on Domino server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We had a slow performance of Domino server few days back and I have collected the semdebug.txt log file data.

7 entries of the below line are preent:

```
ti="004EFA58-C125823A" sq="000020E0" THREAD [15E0:000A-1954] WAITING FOR READ LOCK ON FRWSEM 0x0244 database semaphore (@020F89FC) (D:\IBM\Domino\data\<root_folder>\<dbname.nsf>) (R=2,W=0,WRITER=0000:0000,1STREADER=15E0:077C) FOR 30000 ms
```

I know that the process 15E0 was waiting for the read lock to be released. But I'm not getting what exactly is meant by **WRITER** and **1STREADER** here. The **OWNER** parameter is also not present. I have searched a lot of articles, but this part is a bit confusing.

Why is a **OWNER** parameter not present? What is **WRITER** and **1STREADER**?

Some hints on this would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault, but really it belongs with IBM support. They can guide you through the process of using diagnostic tools to analyze issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/01152009062114PMWEBVDT.htm)'s possible cause: disk fragmentation. Check your disk performance in general at OS level.

Comment: Yes, performance of the disk on which applications were hosted was the cause for the issue. However the exact meaning of all parameters in the the log entry can be provided only by IBM Support apparently as suggested by Richard.